# The constructor AdPreferences(int, int, String) is undefined startapp?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use Startapp for my app, i keep on getting this error i don't know why !
the error is at this line

```
AdPreferences adPreferences =
    new AdPreferences(developers ID,App ID,AdPreferences.TYPE_INAPP_EXIT);
    htmlAd = new HtmlAd(this); htmlAd.load(adPreferences, this);
```

I removed my IDs

Here is the full code

```
public class SplashActivity extends WhatsNewActivity implements OnClickListener
{

private Button mButtonPlay;
private HtmlAd htmlAd = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{



    super.onCreate(icicle);


    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    mButtonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_go);
    mButtonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_splash);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.splash);

    AndroidSDKProvider.setTestMode(true);
    AndroidSDKProvider.initSDK(this);
    AdPreferences adPreferences =
    new AdPreferences(xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,AdPreferences.TYPE_INAPP_EXIT);
    htmlAd = new HtmlAd(this); htmlAd.load(adPreferences, this);





}





@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if(htmlAd != null) {
htmlAd.show();
}
super.onBackPressed();
}


/**
 * {@inheritDoc }
 */
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (v == mButtonPlay)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaintActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
public int getFirstRunDialogTitleRes()
{
    return R.string.first_run_dialog_title;
}

@Override
public int getFirstRunDialogMsgRes()
{
    return R.string.first_run_dialog_message;
}

@Override
public int getWhatsNewDialogTitleRes()
{
    return R.string.whats_new_dialog_title;
}

@Override
public int getWhatsNewDialogMsgRes()
{
    return R.string.whats_new_dialog_message;
}
}
```

Comment: Doesnt look like that constructor is defined.  So if its your code, you should add it in.  If it's a default class, you need to change your constructor to match what is already defined.

Answer (score 0):

developers ID,App ID needs to be of String type and not int.